# Click action Button HTML generated by a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a single servlet java file.
this is my code:

```
            out.append(" <tr>");
            out.append("<th><input type=\"text\" name=\"fname\"></th>");
            out.append("<th><input type=\"text\" name=\"lname\"></th>");
            out.append("<th><input type=\"text\" name=\"date\"></th>");

            out.append("<th><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"></th>");
            out.append(" </tr>");
```

3 text input and a button.
the java servlet creates that HTML, i need to read the content of the 3 inputs, and when the button is pressed i need to call a function with the 3 inputs as parameters.

Thanks for help.

EDIT: code test:

```
    out.append("<form>");
    out.append(" <tr>");
    out.append("<th><input type=\"text\" id=\"fname\" name=\"fname\"></th>");
    out.append("<th><input type=\"text\" name=\"lname\"></th>");
    out.append("<th><input type=\"text\" name=\"date\"></th>");

    out.append("<th><button type=\"submit\"  value=\"Submit\">Submit</button></th>");

    out.append(" </tr>");
    out.append("</form>");



    String fname = null;

    if(request.getParameter("fname")!=null){
    fname=request.getParameter("fname");
    //FUNCTION
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a form tag and on click of the submit button , submit the html form.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not understanding.





You mean something like this? how do i call the java funcion? and how do i get the input text values? EDIT: sorry im new on stack, i added the new code in the main thread so you can read it correctly

Comment: i think i resolved, thank you. i created a generic form with a submit button, then i use request.getparameter to get information about the textboxs

Comment: Yes, thats correct way to create generic form. Please upvote the answer.